# Some of your tests did a full page reload - Unit Testing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing

I'm relatively new to unit tests so forgive me. But I'm getting the following error and have been looking around for a solution but can't really understand the examples I've seen. 
Error:

> Some of your tests did a full page reload!

This is my test causing the issue.

```
it('should download test results', () => {
    expect(scope.downloading).toBeFalsy();
    httpBackend
      .expectGET('http://1.2.3.4/dowloads')
      .respond(mockedProductTest);
    controller.DownloadResults();
    expect(scope.downloading).toBeTruthy();
    httpBackend.flush();
    expect(scope.downloading).toBeFalsy();
});
```

This is my function.

```
this.$scope.downloading = true;
    this.$http.get(
        `${this.$config.serverAddress}downloads}`
    )
    .then(response => {
        this.$scope.downloading = false;
        //Next Line is the one causing issues.
        this.$window.location.href = `${this.$config.serverAddress}download/TestResultszipFullPath=${response.data}`;
    },
```

Comment: I don't really know Angular, but `this.$window.location.href`will literally do a full page reload. That's probably what the testing framework is warning you

Comment: @ChristopherFrancisco Is there a way to get around this error do you know?

Comment: I mean, you are doing a full page reload. So I assume not doing it will fix it. Remove the line for starter